# Plot two functions in ggplot2 with different x range limits

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have plotted linear functions with ggplot as follow:

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=c(0,320)), aes(x)) +
  stat_function(fun=function(x)60.762126*x-549.98, geom="line", colour="black") +
  stat_function(fun=function(x)-0.431181333*x+2.378735e+02, geom="line", colour="black")+
  ylim(-600,600)
```

However, I want the 1st function to be plotted for x ranging from 0 to 12 and the 2nd function to be plotted for x ranging from 12 to max(x).
Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Why not create your data first outside ggplot? Gives you a lot more control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easiest to just calculate the data you need outside of the `ggplot` call first.

```
fun1 <- function(x) 60.762126 * x - 549.98
dat1 <- data.frame(x = c(0, 12), y = NA)
dat1$y <- fun1(dat1$x)

fun2 <- function(x) -0.431181333 * x + 2.378735e+02
dat2 <- data.frame(x = c(12, 320), y = NA)
dat2$y <- fun2(dat2$x)


ggplot(mapping = aes(x, y)) +
  geom_line(data = dat1) +
  geom_line(data = dat2)
```

Or you can join the data for the lines first (as suggested by @Heroka), resulting in an identical plot:

```
dat.com <- rbind(dat1, dat2)
dat.com$gr <- rep(1:2, c(nrow(dat1), nrow(dat2)))

ggplot(dat.com, aes(x, y, group = gr)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: If there are many lines to be drawn, OP might consider combining the data first (with for instance a grouping-variable).